# Node.JS returns a 404 on interrogation of an endpoint that actually exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a web application, started by a previous company, written in Angular.JS. 
 The application exposes a request towards the back-end (written in Node.JS+Express) to gather some data required to fill a table. 
 Specifically, this is the request that the application sends everytime the user enters in the page that holds the table (The config variable holds the access token).

```
return $http.get(API + '/api/myPath/for/Having/Data', config).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
```

handleSuccess and handleError are so defined

```
        handleSuccess: function (res) {
            debugger;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            res.data.success ? deferred.resolve(res.data) : deferred.reject(res.data.message);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        handleError: function (error) {
            return {
                success: false,
                message: error
            };
        }
```

In my back-end I've put an a listener to whatever gets called with the "/api" prefix, like this

```
app.use('/api', authorization.validateToken);
```

And another listener, that should work only if there is no match (written at the very end of the file that handles all the general inquiries of the app)

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Hi, Stack Overflow!');
    res.send({
        success: false,
        status: 404,
        message: 'Invalid Uri Resource'
    });
});
```

And, lastly, this is the endpoint that should get called in the back-end from Angular.js

```
app.get('/api/myPath/for/Having/Data', something.somethingToCall);
```

Here's the funny part: for a reason that I still have to understand, Angular.JS calls that endpoint twice, resulting in one failing procedure (404) and another one that goes smoothly (200).

The operation flow should be like this: Angular calls the back-end --> Node checks the validity of the token --> executes operation if everything goes okay.

The operation is called twice (seen thanks to the Visual Studio Code debugger and Chrome's Network Monitor) and, even though the token's validation process is correctly executed everytime, the first time the next() function will hold the app.all() listener.

Also,even before I start debugging the first request that is sent out, the JavaScript console on Google Chrome warns me that there has been an error such as like "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined", meaning that the request gets executed twice with the first time returning a 404.

```
exports.validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`check user here`);
    // next();
    var token =  //I take the token 
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, require('../../secret'), (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    success: false,
                    status: 500,
                    tokenExpired: true,
                    message: "Effettua nuovamente l'accesso"
                });
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.send({
            success: false,
            status: 406, // Fprbidden
            message: 'User not Authenticated'
        });
    }
};
```

Does anybody know how to help me somehow?
EDIT: this is an example of how Chrome's sees both requests. The screenshot, in particular, refers to the first one that gets called and produces the 404

The CORS is handled in the back-end like this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.headers.origin && (req.headers.origin.match("http:\/\/somewebsite.com.*") || req.headers.origin.match("http:\/\/localhost:8010") )) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
    }

    next();
});
```

Also, I'm adding the endpoint that needs to be called. This also exploits MongoDB + Mongoose for querying the DataBase and return stuff to the front-end. The parameters that I'm passing are pageSize (how many elements per page) and the current page number

```
exports.getAds = (req, res) => {

  var criteria = req.body || {};
  var pageSize = criteria['pageSize'] ? Number(criteria['pageSize']) : undefined;
  var pageNumber = criteria['pageNumber'] ? Number(criteria['pageNumber']) : undefined;

  var sort = criteria.sort || { createdAt: 'desc' };

  if (criteria.customerName) criteria.customerName = { $regex: `.*${criteria.customerName}.*`, $options: 'i' };
  if (criteria.spentEuros) criteria.spentEuros.$gte = criteria.spentEuros;
  if (criteria.referralMail) criteria.referralMail = { $regex: `.*${criteria.referralMail}.*`, $options: 'i' };


  console.log(criteria);

  var columns = "customerName duration spentEuros";

  if (pageSize && pageNumber) {
    Adv.paginate(criteria, {
      page: pageNumber,
      limit: pageSize,
      select: columns,
      sort: sort
    }, function (err, result) {
      if (!err) res.status(200).send({ success: true, data: result });
      else res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: err });
    });
  } else {
    Adv.find(criteria)
      .select(columns)
      .sort(sort)
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (!err) res.status(200).send({ success: true, data: result });
        else res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: err });
      });
  }

};
```

EDIT2: Solution to the question: adding an app.options listener in the back-end (as pointed out by @slebetman), alongside with the already existing app.get one, solved the issue

[image: The first endpoint call that produces the 404]

Comment: `app.use` just registers middleware. Do you have an `app.get` handling that endpoint?

Comment: Yes of course: the second time it gets executed, the endpoint gets correctly called and returns the desired values

Comment: FYI 406 is Not Acceptable, relating to content type negotiation, not Forbidden (which is 403).

Comment: @GianmarcoF. - Does the browser code actually see the result of the `get`?

Comment: @GianmarcoF. - Can you reduce the problem to a [mcve] that people can copy and paste into their own setups to try to help? (The above is already close, I'd say, just missing a couple of small bits.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've also added the code that gets called in the back-end. Do you think it might be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's the funny part: for a reason that I still have to understand, Angular.JS calls that endpoint twice...

That sounds a lot like the browser sending a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) preflight `OPTIONS` request, followed by a `GET`. Check the HTTP verb being used, and be sure you're handling `OPTIONS` (not just `GET`) if you need to support CORS on your endpoint. (If you're not expecting this to be a cross-origin request, check the origin of the page relative to the origin of the API call, something [protocol, port, domain] seems to be different — **if** it's an `OPTIONS` call.)

Comment: Yes it gets called as an OPTIONS (due to CORS) both times, but firstly it gets the 404, then it gets the 200. I've added a screenshot of the first response

Comment: @GianmarcoF. I don't see anywhere you handle OPTIONS. You are only handling GET (and I presume POST in other places). OPTIONS is like GET and POST. Since you are not handling OPTIONS the request goes to `all('*')`

Comment: @slebetman see the edit on my question. It's handled on the back-end

Comment: @GianmarcoF. -- It looks like express supports `app.options()`. So you just need to add an `options()` handler

Comment: @GianmarcoF. I only see you doing `app.get('/api/myPath/for/Having/Data', something.somethingToCall)`. You also need to do `app.options('/api/myPath/for/Having/Data', something.somethingToCall)`

Comment: @GianmarcoF. -- The issue is not with the CORS headers. The issue is the browser making an OPTIONS request before a GET request. You are handling the headers correctly. You are not handling OPTIONS requests

Comment: I have many other methods in GET and POST that responds correctly from a CORS request. Before running in app.options, I'd like to try to solve the issue without using it

Comment: @GianmarcoF. - As slebetman said, the code in your (updated) question doesn't handle `OPTIONS`, it just handles `GET`. Unlike the browser-side, the server-side of this is not automatic. You need to explicitly handle `OPTIONS` via [`app.options`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD) (or using a middleware that does it for you, like [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)). *"Before running in app.options, I'd like to try to solve the issue without using it."* If it's a cross-origin request requiring a preflight, you *can't* solve it just by responding to `GET`.

Comment: Ok so essentially, the back-end part in which I append the CORS headers is okay BUT, because the endpoint is not listening in OPTIONS, it won't get interrogated.
But why then the call is executed twice, resulting in one failing and one succeding?
Consider that I have many other endpoints that are called from that very same front-end and returns a correct answer (and they're not listening on OPTIONS)

Comment: Changing to app.options and keeping the app.get solved the issue but it keeps get called twice and Chrome's JavaScript Console still tells me the error "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" which I honestly can't understand, since now even tough the request is done twice, it returns every time data

Comment: @GianmarcoF. - It's **not** being called twice. There's an `OPTIONS` request (just the one), and then there's a `GET` request (just the one). That's how [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) works when a preflight is needed. See the linked spec for details. Re "cannot read property `data` of undefined," that'll be a relatively simple error in the code somewhere. *"...even tough the request is done twice, it returns every time data..."* You don't need to send the data twice. Send it once, in response to `GET`. `OPTIONS` (for CORS) is purely about the headers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I'll definetely give a look to the spec!